# What is PSU(1,1) PSU(2,1)? Is there a general group of the form PSU(n,m)?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I have seen it written about groups PSU(1,1), PSU(2,1). But what exactly are these? The definitions were not given, and I can't seem to find a definition online.

Moreover is there a general class of these groups of the form PSU(n,m)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unitary group of signature $(n,m)$ is the group of matrices preserving a Hermitian form of signature $(n,m)$, and is isomorphic to this group preserving a particularly simple such form (a diagonal one):
$$\operatorname{U}(n,m) = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix} \in \operatorname{GL}_{n+m}(\mathbb{C}) : AA^* - BB^* = I_n,~ DD^*-CC^* = I_m,~ AC^* = BD^* \right\}$$

The special unitary group $\operatorname{SU}(n,m) = \left\{ M \in \operatorname{U}(n,m) : \det(M) = 1 \right\}$ is restricted to those matrices of determinant $1$.

The projective special unitary group $\operatorname{PSU}(n,m) = SU(n,m)/Z$ is the quotient of this group be its subgroup of scalar matrices $Z=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} zI_n & 0 \\ 0 & zI_m \end{bmatrix} : |z|=1, z^{n+m} = 1 \right\}$.

See the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group) for more information and references.

Comment: Are you sure that the $z^{m+n}=1$ is enforced? If it's just quotienting out by the centre, then it wouldn't be. But I am new to this, so are there varying definitions?

Comment: For $\operatorname{P\textbf{S}U}$, yes. For $\operatorname{PU}$, no. To be in SU, the determinant has to be one, and the determinant is $z^{n+m}$. For U, we just need $|z|=1$.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: what are $ A,B,C,D$ ? are they matrices? is this a set of block matrices?